# Mysql count query results in empty set

Tags: mysql

I am executing the following query and getting an empty result set back. What could be the problem?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM STATION_METRICS 
WHERE metric_label = 'Pressure' 
AND station_id = 1 
AND metric_timestamp >= '2022-11-29' 
AND metric_timestamp <= '2022-12-06' 
ORDER BY metric_timestamp ASC 
LIMIT 18446744073709551615 OFFSET 50;
```

It confuses me because when I execute the same query but without count(*) like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM STATION_METRICS 
WHERE metric_label = 'Pressure' 
AND station_id = 1 
AND metric_timestamp >= '2022-11-29' 
AND metric_timestamp <= '2022-12-06' 
ORDER BY metric_timestamp ASC 
LIMIT 18446744073709551615 OFFSET 50;
```

it returns rows normally, but the count does not.
I am using limit with large number as a workaround since offset cannot be used alone.
Also, when I remove limit and offset, count works normally as expected.

Comment: What happens if you remove offset 50?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not make much sense to be using `OFFSET` with a top level count query.  The `COUNT(*)` will return a single record containing the count over the table, given the limit and sort.  But then, your inclusion of `OFFSET` will force the cursor past the single record result set to nothing.

For your first count query, most likely you should just be running:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM STATION_METRICS
WHERE metric_label = 'Pressure' AND
      station_id = 1 AND
      metric_timestamp >= '2022-11-29' AND metric_timestamp < '2022-12-07';
```

Comment: Yes, I got confused and had wrong idea of how this should work. I though that first offset and limit are applied and then the count counts the rows.

Comment: AFAIK sorting (`ORDER BY`), limit, and offset, occur _after_ the rest of the query has already evaluated.  To get the behavior you want, you may subquery and take the count.

Comment: Yes, now that I understand the problem I think there is easier solution. Maybe I just can count elements without offset and then remove the offset from the count. This should give me the result that I am looking for I think.